# cors error on netlify client site calling api endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, netlify

My site domain is `example.com`. In my client app I have this logic:

```
api_call('process.env.NODE_ENV' + '/jobs')
```

so after netlifly deployed the client app I can see it's calling the right api endpoint which is `api.example.com`. I've also tested it, it's alright. But somehow I saw this error in the console

```
`OPTIONS https://api.example.com/login 404 (Not Found)
Failed to load https://api.example.com/login: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'https://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.`
```

Do I missed something?

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this error in my client app also. If you understand what CORS is, you'd know that it is a header that has to be present in the API so that the programmer can specify who all can access that API. 
So if your API does not have this header and your client app is in a different domain, your app is not allowed to access that API.

```
 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

This line means that you need  CORS header in your API (which is the requested resource).
No change is needed in the client app

Comment: why I can access it via postman?

Comment: I added this in my node.js server

`const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'https://api.example.com',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions))` but still have the same error.

Comment: [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)  I used this chrome extension and I was able to access the API  even without CORS header. But This is a short-term solution. To answer your other question, postman is a dev tool, CORS is a security mechanism enforced by browsers. So postman should work.

Comment: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44738078/node-js-cors-request-header-field-authorization-is-not-allowed-by-access-con) I found this link helpful. You can try this. Also, remember CORS  header has to be in the response, not the request because the API  has to send that header to the browser

Comment: ok I understand now it's allowed in postmen. But in localhost I don't need CORS either, why? is localhost doesn't enforce CORS?

Comment: It is about the domain your API and your app are present in. So if your app and API run on different hosts, you will need CORS. I guess you are not having a problem because you might be using the same domain for both

Comment: others having issue too with ssl https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41347766/how-to-use-https-with-letsencrypt-socket-io-and-node-js